# Why would a WiFi WebSocket ever disconnect? How to make more robust?

Tags: websocket

I have a bunch of lighting strips that are controlled by ESP32 chips that provide a WebSocket where you can push lighting data.  The master pushes 30 frames per second, one 24-bit value per pixel, so for a 512 light strip:

512 x 3 bytes x 30 frames = 46K/sec

So the PC runs an app that pushes those frames to the ESP32 chips on the WiFi network 30 times a second.  But each connection will fail randomly every minute or two.  Bigger data increases the fail rate.

I try to keep the connection open at all times, and in fact will monitor and re-open the connection when it fails or closes, which it will every minute or two sometimes, sometimes more often, sometimes less.

My question is why does a WebSocket on a reliable wifi network EVER close itself, and how can I prevent it or what can I do to make it more robust?

Currently, I watch for the close (normally comes in as code 54, peer reset) and then re-open.  But I can't tell why it'd ever close.  I have about -35dB of signal strength, which is excellent.

The implementation is the ESP32 Websockets projects, but short of a bug, the platform shouldn't matter for this discussion.

Comment: It looks like the socket is receiving corruption - improper opcodes and mismatched data length when I debug the websocket stack, and the code then correctly closes the connection.  But shouldn't TCP/IP be guaranteeing me a clean, error-free stream?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Websocket impl on the esp32 is pretty unreliable at high loads.  I retargetted my code to the unix socket layer and it has performed flawlessly since.